# How do I access the kippt api using only jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, cross-domain

I am trying to access my kippt bookmarks using [their api](https://kippt.com/developers/).

The api looks simple enough and I can access it in my terminal doing a `curl` request. But when I try a cross-domain jsonp request with jquery ajax in the browser, I get a `401 UNAUTHORIZED` error.

Here is my code:

```
    var authconfig = {
    api_url: 'https://kippt.com/api/',
    username: 'amit_e',
    password: '*****'
}

$.ajax({
    url: authconfig.api_url + 'lists',
    username: authconfig.username,
    password: authconfig.password,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    async: false,
    type: 'GET'
}).done(function(data){
    console.log(data); 
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    console.log(errorThrown);
});
```

I am using jquery 1.9 working on `http://localhost:3501` on a simple python server. I have no experience working with jsonp. So please help me get the json data back. The returned data should look like:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "limit": 20,
        "next": "/api/clips/?limit=20&offset=20",
        "offset": 0,
        "previous": null,
        "total_count": 33
    },
    "objects": [
        {
            "id": 15,
            ...
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

UPDATE:

Adding async: false as an option to my ajax request brought me back my data. Does anybody have any idea why?

Comment: You should check your credentials. Also, if i recall correctly setting `dataType` to `jsonp` will automatically add the `callback` parameter. Did you check what is the form of the request in your Network tab of your browser?

Comment: @Alexander double checked my creds - doesn't work - same error.

Comment: Can you clarify where are you handling `data` returned from the server? I believe you are not using correctly the callback

Comment: @Alexander I have updated the code to reflect the point where data is getting spit out by the api. But now I am wondering why is `async: false`is needed..

Comment: Try the code as you have it now, removing the `async` option. Use `console.log(data)`, not `console.log('done')` as you had before. Does this still works?

Comment: Oh yeah it does. What the hell just happened?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24319/discussion-between-amit-erandole-and-alexander)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you were using a synchronous approach for an asynchronous functions as AJAX ones are. For an example of a wrong approach:

```
var f = function(){
    $.ajax({
        ...
    }).done(function(data){
        console.log('done');
    });
    /* data isn't available yet - data is undefined */
    return data;
};
```

AJAX functions return immediately. Even though, the responses haven't arrived yet. The `done` callback will be triggered when the data is returned from the server and you shall react to it.